# Removing an item from an AngularFirestoreCollection subscribed with snapshotChanges then navigating to the collection route returns duplicate items

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have [a small list management example application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfire-collection-remove-item) consisting of two Angular 6 components and a service:

**ShapeListComponent**

A list of shapes each with an edit button that are read from a Cloud Firestore collection, subscribed to via snapshotChanges() call on an AngularFirestoreCollection call and held in an rxjs observable.

**ShapeEditComponent**

An edit page for each shape, which allows the name to be updated, or the shape to be removed from the collection. Upon editing or removing or updating the shape, the user is navigated back to the shape-list route.

**ShapeService**

Wraps the calls to AngularFire.

***The Problem***

Removing an item does not behave as I expect. On being routed back to the list, the removed item is still there, and every item after deleted item in the list is duplicated.

The document data visible in the Firebase Console, however, is deleted correctly, and no duplicates appear.

Is anyone able to shed any light on whether my approach to using AngularFire with Cloud Firestore and rxjs is flawed, or should this work correctly?

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create a new Firebase project
2. Setup the database feature (selecting Cloud Firestore Beta in test mode)
3. In your firebase project settings, select "Add Firebase to your web app" and copy the js containing your connection information (ignoring the last line that initialises the app as this is done in the module declaration below) to clipboard.

   ```
   // Initialise Firebase
   var config = {
     apiKey: "...",
     authDomain: "...",
     databaseURL: "...",
     projectId: "...",
     storageBucket: "...",
     messagingSenderId: "..."
   };
   ```
4. [Go to the stackblitz example I've created](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfire-collection-remove-item) and in `app.module.ts` replace the same snippet, renaming the `config` variable to `firebaseConfig`
5. Add a few shapes
6. Edit the first shape in the list and hit the "Remove" button.
7. The resulting list contains above mentioned duplicates.

**Other Notes**

The same problematic behaviour is NOT observed when the remove functionality is included within the list component (and no router navigation is done). ([See this example which behaves *correctly*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularefirestore-collection-remove-works) - also needs pointing to your Firebase Cloud Firestore project)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue which I "solved" by relying on the `shareReplay(1)` operator in the `snapshotChanges` observable:

```
this.shapes$ = this.shapes.snapshotChanges().pipe((shareReplay(1), map(actions => {
  return actions.map(action => ({key: action.payload.doc.id, ...action.payload.doc.data()})));
});
```

I admit I haven't figured out *why* the issue crops up and I am not happy with the hack. Switching to `valueChanges()` (and therefore losing the ID) also got rid of the duplicates.